# Contraction Mapping Conditions

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, functions

Consider $f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ continuous and uniformly bounded, and consider the iteration

$$ x^{(k+1)} = \frac{1}{k} \sum_{i=1}^{k} f\left( x^{(i)} \right) + x^{(i)} $$

for some given initial conditions $x^{(0)}, x^{(1)}, \dots$.

Under what (regularity) conditions on $f$, is the sequence $\{ x^{(k)} \}_k^{\infty}$ converging?

For instance, trivially, if $f(\cdot) = 0$ then $x^{(k)}$ converges to the mean among the initial conditions. Now I am wondering if the Lipschitz constant of $f$ may help.

Does $x^{(k)}$ converge if $f(\cdot)$ is affine?